# Foreach result echo do duplicate row output (in the beginning without variable, then with variable)

Tags: php, json

**I'm getting some data via api as json:**

Response headers:

```
200 success
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with, authorization, content-type
access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-length: 1046
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 25 Jul 2021 14:14:51 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: nginx
x-vendon-api-requests: 2
```

Response data:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "result": {
        "id": 3075531,
        "stock_id": 184445,
        "stock_article": "Parfum 2 ml 047 women",
        "selections": [
            {
                "selection": 11,
                "label": "11",
                "price": 1,
                "pricelist": null,
                "pricelist_type": null,
                "payment_device_type": null
            }
        ],
        "type": "PRODUCT",
        "name": "Parfum 2 ml 047 women",
        "units": null,
        "amount": 10,
        "amount_max": 11,
        "amount_standart": 11,
        "amount_critical": 3,
        "refill_unit_size": 1,
        "min_refill": 1,
        "refillable": true,
        "last_purchase": 1624011420,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "recipe": [],
        "ingredient_line": null,
        "critical": false,
        "extraction_time_enabled": null,
        "min_extraction_time": null,
        "max_extraction_time": null,
        "product_price_group": null,
        "has_route_planing_expiry_date": false
    }
}
```

Then decoding and doing `foreach()` to output only variable that i need with:

code

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($html, true);
foreach($decodedJson as $answer) {
    echo 'Item:' .$answer['name'].' available '.$answer['amount'].'pcs.'; 
}
```

But i'm stuck, cos getting duplicates in output(echo row without variable, than echo row with variable, can't fix this, can someone help?

Output

```
Item: available pcs.Item:Parfum 2 ml 047 women available 10pcs.
```

Comment: `$answer = $decodedJson['result'];` and drop the loop. The "empty" output is because you're treating the `"code": 200,` as if it were an actual answer.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Thank You

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Amimistik "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

Answer (score 2):

Your json response data shown by you is not an array of objects, its just single object data.

So no need of loop, just do like below:

```
$answer = json_decode($html, true);
echo 'Item:'.$answer['result']['name'].' available '.$answer['result']['amount'].'pcs.';
```